# Which graph type for these scenarios

Tags: javascript, d3.js, directed-graph, undirected-graph

I am trying to build a tool to visualize the dependencies for all services across an enterprise however none seem to meet the criteria.

I have looked into directed acyclic graphs, but several services can call each other, so that's out.

I have look into various tree structures, but there can be multiple roots. so thats out.

I have looked into org charts through D3, but that's out as, again, multiple services can call each other.

This data does not have a strictly hierarchal structure.

I would like to narrow down the correct service that can take in data (represented in the attached image) and visualize it for me dynamically.

What graph type does this represent and are there any libraries that can visualize it?

**I'm leaning toward just using an undirected graph and when a service is clicked, just display its upstream and downstream dependencies**

[image]

Comment: _"What graph type does this represent"_ - uhm... a block-diagram?

Comment: Hmmm... yes, that seem closest to what i'm trying to accomplish. I'm not sure how I didn't come across this in all the graph visualization stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You simply have a [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph). Your example is a [weakly connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)) one, but you might also have one with multiple components.

Yes, it's not acyclic if there are circular dependencies. Yes, it's not a tree if there is not a single root; and it's not a forest (with multiple roots) either if there is no hierarchy.

> I'm leaning toward just using an undirected graph

No, since your edges have arrows (directions) on them. You distinguish between the calling service and the called service. You want to distinguish between upstream (incoming edges) and downstream (outgoing edges). All these make the graph directed.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Do you know a javascript based service that can visualize directed graphs? It seems all the big ones only do DAG's. I can do a force directed graph, but there is no out of the box solution for a static FDG. I was originally going to just use an undirected graph to show the connection and then on click, show which is the upstream/downstream. service. That would remove the acyclic problem. That is most likely the route I will take if there are no libraries to visualize the above.